# Can intermediate stream operations be encapsulated without breaking the pipeline?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

With Java 8 Streams, is it possible to encapsulate and reuse intermediate stream operations in some way that won't break the stream pipeline?

Consider this example from the [Java Tutorial on streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/):

```
double average = roster
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
    .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

Suppose I need to use the filter and mapToInt operations in different places throughout my code.  I might want try and to encapsulate that logic so it can be reused, for example:

```
IntStream maleAges(Stream<Person> stream) {
    return stream
        .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
        .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
}
```

This is nice, but to use it I might have to make a mess of the stream pipeline.  For example, if I want the average age of men named Bob:

```
double averageBob =
    maleAges(roster
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> "Bob".equals(p.getName()))
    )
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

Is there some better way to do it?  I'm thinking of something along these lines:

```
double averageBob = roster
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> "Bob".equals(p.getName()))
    .apply(this::maleAges) // Doesn't compile
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

Comment: What about `int maleAges(Person p) { return p.getAge(); }` and then use `.map(this::maleAges)`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That accounts for the 'ages', but not for the 'male' :)

Comment: Essentially, I'm looking for a way to encapsulate multiple operations of different types and insert them into the pipeline as though they were a single operation.

Comment: Oh sorry, then something like this: `return p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE ? p.getAge() : 0;`. For this case, it will work as expected.

Comment: I would recommend that instead of trying to apply a single method that contains a bunch of business logic, split it into smaller pieces as shown in this example.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not quite the same, for example `{Bob (42), Sally (23), Jack (18)}` would map to `{42 0 18}` using your example, but the goal is to map to `{42 18}`.  The filter is important.

Comment: what's wrong with method call?

Comment: Oh right. Understood. I have some research to do then :)

Comment: @AdamSkywalker well it works fine, it just looks messy.  And if I had a more complex example with multiple encapsulations that I want to chain together, it could get very ugly in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances standard Stream API among other features has the `chain` method which works exactly as your proposed `apply`:

```
double averageBob = StreamEx.of(roster)
        .filter(p -> "Bob".equals(p.getName()))
        .chain(this::maleAges) // Compiles!
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
```

Also one possible alternative is to return a function from `maleAges`:

```
Function<Stream<Person>, IntStream> maleAges() {
    return stream -> stream
        .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
        .mapToInt(Person::getAge);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
double averageBob = StreamEx.of(roster)
        .filter(p -> "Bob".equals(p.getName()))
        .chain(maleAges()) // Compiles!
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
```

This way you may easily parameterize your encapsulated operation. For example:

```
Function<Stream<Person>, IntStream> agesForSex(Person.Sex sex) {
    return stream -> stream
        .filter(p -> p.getGender() == sex)
        .mapToInt(Person::getAge);
}

double averageBob = StreamEx.of(roster)
        .filter(p -> "Bob".equals(p.getName()))
        .chain(agesForSex(Person.Sex.MALE)) // Compiles!
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
```

Comment: Very nice, that's exactly what I was expecting :)

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be to instead taking a Stream, to take a single Person and emit an IntStream such as :

```
 final Predicate<Person> isMale = p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE;
 final Function<Person, IntStream> maleAges = person -> isMale.test(person)
            ? IntStream.of(person.age)
            : IntStream.empty();
 final double averageT = roster
                .stream()
                .flatMapToInt(maleAges)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
```

This way you can reuse your maleAges function anywhere !

Comment: This is a great solution, the only drawback though is that stream operations cannot be used in the encapsulated function.  So while it works well for the example it might be a bit too clunky in general use.

Comment: I agree, when I wrote it I felt that getting a Person and returning an IntStream was a bit flawn. It's a bit more "poetic" (because I believe that code can be true poetry) to have a function that based on a ´Stream<Person> ´ returns an ´IntStream´, it feels like more natural and native. I had a discussion about it with my colleague today explaining me that a library named Jool is providing more or less the same features as StreamEx. I guess my answer would be the best for someone who does not want to rely on external dependencies and want plain Java 8 features !

Comment: I think this is what you're referring to?  https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL  It looks like a viable alternative to Tagir's StreamEx, thanks for sharing!